# Is there a way to permanently add to a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I want to create a program that stores my race data in lists sorted my race length(I'm a runner). So when I add it, it add temporarily and as soon as I restart the code, it deletes the old one. I want it to permanently change the code and be added permanently.
my code:

```
#All the sub-folders
fivek = []
tenk = []
twomi = []
sixteen = []
eight = []
four = []
two = []
Half = []
Full = []

#choose which folder
distance = input("Length of Race? (5k, 10k, 2mi, 1600, 800, 400, 200, Half, Full)")
if distance == "5k":
    time=str(input("What was your time? (Put date in parenthesis Ex. 20:00(1-1-20))"))
    fivek.append(time)
    print(fivek)
```

am I being clear enough? Let me know if I'm being too hazy.

so using csv like this?

```
import csv

time = []
length = []
place = []

timeResult = input("What was your time?")
lengthResult = input("What was the race length?")
placeResult = input("Where was the race?")

pace.append(placeResult)
time.append(timeResult)
length.append(lengthResult)

with open('times.csv', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)
    thewriter.writerow([length, time, place])
```

Comment: Do you mean you want your program to edit its own source code?

Comment: It would probably be useful to research / describe the problem in terms "save" and "load", such as persisting the data to a file on disk. The list objects themselves are in-memory and will cease to exist, along with any content, on program termination.

Comment: Also, "yes there is" is an answer to the question. A more useful title might be: "How can I permanently add to a list?" (although this could still use clarification; see above comment(s)).

Comment: Modifying the code itself is _possible_, although _not generally advisable_. This is just a form of a "save" where the storage mechanism is updating a given Python source file: it would be much cleaner just to modify an external data file that is read. Anyway, there is no built-in operation to modify-the-current-code as such.

Answer (score 0):

No. Python lists are objects that are created in memory. Memory is empty when your Python script starts, and the objects in it disappear when your script ends. So what you need to do is fill your list from a form of permanent storage, such as a file on your disk. i.e. you don't want to modify the code itself to contain your data. Instead, your code reads in data from an external source.

So you might want to look at the `csv` library:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html. This allows you to read from a file on disk at the start of your script to populate a list initially. You then add entries to the list in your script, and at the end, save the updated list back to disk. A tabular csv (comma separated values) file has the advantage that it is plain text, so it can be read by a great range of other software, and is especially well-suited to being opened in a spreadsheet if you want to inspect your data that way. Pickling is a way of directly saving Python objects to disk, but the resulting files aren't directly readable by anything except Python itself.

Lastly, you might find it convenient to save all of your data in a single table, with a column for race length, and another column for race time. This allows for a lot more flexibility for analysis later on. Inside your code, after reading in a single csv file formatted in that way, you would get a single list of dictionaries, where each entry is a Python dictionary that has a key (the race length) and a value (the race time).

Comment: I think you will need to open the file in "append" mode, so that new rows get added to the file, rather than overwriting the existing contents, e.g. `with open('times.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:`